# Job.Execute immediately triggers while scheduling the job with passed StartTimeUTC

Tags: quartz.net

I am new to Quartznet schedulers. I am trying to implement
"CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl" trigger. I set a passed date (a day in
2010 year) to the trigger.

When I call the ScheduleJob method by passing the Jobdetail
& Triggers, it immediately triggers the Job.Execute method. Whether I
am missing anything. Please guide me in correct way.

Please look at the following sample code,

```
class Program
{
    private static IScheduler _scheduler;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Day);
        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        _scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        _scheduler.Start();
        AddJob();
    }

    public static void AddJob()
    {
        IJob myJob = new MyJob(); //This Constructor needs to be parameterless
        JobDetailImpl jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl("Group1", "Group1", myJob.GetType());
        CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl trigger = new CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl("Group1", "Group1", IntervalUnit.Week, 2);
        trigger.StartTimeUtc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).AddSeconds(15);
        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        Console.WriteLine("Next : {0}", trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc().Value.ToLocalTime());
    }
}

internal class MyJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing the job...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior if you don't set the misfire instruction. Set it to DoNothing, which is 2.